# No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to submit the form its giving me the error

```
No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"
```

the files are: new.html.erb
this file which contains the form with a text field and text area:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

here the url: is to match post request which is a create

form's title

```
<%= f.label :title %><br>
```

form's text field

```
<%= f.text_field :title %></p>
```

form's title

```
<%= f.label :text %><br>
```

form's text area

```
<%= f.text_area :text %></p>           
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

route file is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :article
end
```

controller is
the controller with its methods new and create

whenever I submit the form its giving the error, even I used the URL: articles_path which for default post request, I used @articles also in the form but it is giving me the same error. I am new to the Rails so I tried many ways but I could not find the solution

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new #new method which is a get request
  end

  def create #create method which is a post request
  end
end
```

whenever I submit the form its giving the error, even I used the url: articles_path which for default post request. and I kept

```
def create
end
```

in the controller

Comment: the routes file I added resources :articles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change:

```
resources :article
```

to:

```
resources :articles #plural
```

that way it will map to:

```
articles_path    POST    /articles(.:format)     articles#create
```

Comment: I changed to resources :articles but its giving me the same error

Answer (score 24):

The reason why this occurs for many people using this tutorial is that they don't reload the form after changing the **url** option in the **form_for** helper.

Be sure to **reload a fresh copy of the form before trying to submit it** (you need the form to have the most recent form submission url).

Answer (score 3):

I changed app/views/articles/new.html.erb from:

`<%= form_for :article do |f| %>`

to:

`<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>`

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer on the official guideline.

Because this route goes to the very page that you're on right at the moment, and that route should only be used to display the form for a new article.

Edit the form_with line inside app/views/articles/new.html.erb to look like this:

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

Comment: But as @Wibbly answered above, failing to reload the form page after changing the erb code is probably what trips people up.  It's a critical step (reloading) that isn't mentioned in the tutorial...

Comment: Also it should be noted that the latest documentation does not include this step.

Answer (score 2):

Your actions/methods in the controller do nothing. It should be something like:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create 
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

 private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit()# here go you parameters for an article
  end

end
```

In the view:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

Comment: I added above code to my application but it still giving me the error No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"

Comment: Have you restarted the rails server after editing the config/routes.rb (in the way Wali Ali answered to you)?

Answer (score 2):

`RedZagogulin`s answer is right - that is the code you need to use in your `articles` controller

--

**Routes**

The clue to your problem is here:

```
No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"
```

Typically, when using the [correct routing structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles #-> needs to be controller name
```

You'll find that the `new` action is `GET`, not `POST`. This leads me to believe your system is set up incorrectly (it's trying to send the form data to `articles/new`, when it should just send to `[POST] articles`

[image]

If you follow the steps outlined by `RedZagogulin`, it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

I was continually running into this problem and it came down to the fact that I had the following code in my navbar:

```
<%= link_to "Blog", controller: 'articles' %>
```

I switched to this and it all started working:

```
<%= link_to "Blog", articles_path %>
```

I'm still new to this so the different ways of doing things sometimes gets confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In your case,
at first change the

```rb
#/config/routes.rb

resources :article
```

to

```rb
#/config/routes.rb

resources :articles #plural
```

```rb
# Changing this in Plural naming if your file name
# in #/app/view
# is plural
# (ex: /app/view/articles)
#
# and controller and it's class is also in plural naming
# (ex:
# in #/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb file
# class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
#
# end)
```

In some cases, we need to add a **Post** routes to make a **Post Request** of the form. Just add the lines in routes file:

```rb
#/config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :articles #plural
  post '/articles/new' => 'articles#create'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working, I needed to combine instructions for two answers. First, I added a specific route in routes.rb to handle POST requests to '/articles/new':

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "articles#index"

  resources :articles
  post '/articles/new' => 'articles#create'
end
```

And then I had to change the first line of the form to this `<%= form_with model: @aricle do |form| %>`:

```rb
<h1>New Article</h1>

<%= form_with model: @aricle do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```