# routing error for an message/article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I been making a website and a followed a guide to make a message using rails. But, when I click 'Save', it comes up with an routing error:

```
   Routing Error
   No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"

   Rails.root: C:/Users/yahshef/sites/game

   Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
   Routes

   Routes match in priority from top to bottom

   Helper   HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
   Path / Url           
   welcome_index_path   GET /welcome/index(.:format)    welcome#index
   articles_path    GET /articles(.:format) articles#index
   POST /articles(.:format) articles#create
   new_article_path GET /articles/new(.:format) articles#new
   edit_article_path    GET /articles/:id/edit(.:format)    articles#edit
   article_path GET /articles/:id(.:format) articles#show
   PATCH    /articles/:id(.:format) articles#update
   PUT  /articles/:id(.:format) articles#update
   DELETE   /articles/:id(.:format) articles#destroy
   root_path    GET /   welcome#index
```

My application_controller.rb:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     def index
       @articles = Article.all
     end

     def show
       @article = Article.find(params[:id])
     end

     def new
     end

     def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    private
        def article_params
             params.require(:article).permit(:title, :receiver, :text)
        end
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    end
```

My show.html.erb:

```
    <p>
      <strong>Title:</strong>
      <%= @article.title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Receiver:</strong>
      <%= @article.receiver %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Text:</strong>
      <%= @article.text %>
    </p>
```

My 20150609013912_create_articles.rb:

```
    class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :articles do |t|
          t.string :title
          t.string :receiver
          t.text :text

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

My new.html.erb

```
    <h1>New Message</h1>
    <%= form_for :article do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :receiver %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :receiver %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :text %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :text %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
```

And my index.html.erb:

```
    <h1>Listing messages</h1>

     <table>
       <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Receiver</th>
        <th>Text</th>
       </tr>

     <% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= article.title %></td>
          <td><%= article.receiver %></td>
          <td><%= article.text %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
```

Any results for this routing error? Thanks

Comment: show the full error message from development.log file..

Comment: Show the `articles_controller` code

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23865236/1270789) describes how to correctly implement your `new` and `create`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file called `application_controller.rb` with a bunch of methods for Article in it. You should, instead, have a filed called `articles_controller.rb` with all of those article related methods in it. Rails can't find the save method because it can't find the file that it expects save to be in.

You could fix your problem by changing the line:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

to:

```
class ArticlesController < ActionController::Base
```

This file should be saved to `your_app/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb`

You'd still need another Application Controller file, however. Just so you know, the Application Controller is not related to a specific model in your application, but is concerned with providing general methods (particularly helper methods) to the rest of your application.

Comment: Ohh! God.. what a mess OP did. :/

Comment: The location of the file to be saved is `your_app/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb` not `your_app/app/assets/controllers/articles_controller.rb`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written in `ApplicationController` should be in 'ArticlesController'.

It should be like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  # Your methods for the articles controller
end
```

And the path to the `articles_controller` should be `path_to_your_app/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb` and your `views` under 'path_to_your_app/app/views/articles/'