# Getting Started with Rails 5 tutorial, No route matches [POST] "/articles/new",

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am following this tutorial: Getting Started with Rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I have searched on stack: No route matches [POST] “/articles/new” [No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864868/no-route-matches-post-articles-new) and the recommended spelling correction did not help with my error.

You can find my git: https://github.com/tomile/rails5Blog/tree/adding-partial.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb (didnt copy paste whole file)

```
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
```

...

```
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Article</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

$rake routes

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
         articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
                  POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
      new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
                  POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
      new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
     edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
          article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
                  PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
                  PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
                  DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

Comment: Can you show  full **articles_controller.rb** file.

Comment: Here is a link to the file. https://github.com/tomile/rails5Blog/blob/adding-partial/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb .  The "issue" is where I didn't follow the tutorial and used the symbol :article instead of @article in the _form.html.erb file. Now I am trying to understand the difference why it worked as a symbol in one file and an instance variable in another file.

Comment: Now it's working fine?

Comment: Govind, yes it is working after changing in _form.html.erb from :article to @article.  Still not understanding why a symbol works in one file and an instance variable works in the other file.

Comment: @article is the actual object being edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing new route is of type GET. 
Second thing is that when we use form_for we provide a instance to it.

So in your articles controller

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

and then in form use

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

It will point the form action to create method of article.

Comment: Thank you muchly!  <%= form_for :article do |f| %> is where the fix was needed.  Now I am reviewing the difference between the use of a symbol verses the instance variable in a form_for helper. I used the code <%= form_for @article do |f| %>, and the error was resolved and the code is flowing smoothly.

Comment: As the instance @article is new record of Article so the path added to action of form will be to hit the create action and if we are editing the article, we have already existing @ article instance then it will hit the edit action by default.

Answer (score 0):

One step of tutorial is missed by you.
You must change first row of form to following:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

After that form works fine.